# QGIS Natural Breaks with raster file

Tags: qgis, raster, legend, reclassify

I know it is possible to use natural Breaks legends with vector files in QGIS. Is this possible also with raster files? Actually I want to reclassify raster files by using Natural Breaks.

Answer (score 4):

No it is not possible to classify the image using `Natural break`. In QGIS 2.18.9 `Quantile` was added in the classification which was not exist in QGIS 2.14.15, as you can see below:

QGIS 2.18.9 has 3 options:

- Continuous
- Equal interval
- Quantile

[image]

QGIS 2.14.15 has only 2 options:

- Continuous
- Equal interval

[image]